# Using axis coordination to represent rotation matrix instead of angles

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, rotations

[Euler angles](http://personal.maths.surrey.ac.uk/st/T.Bridges/SLOSH/3-2-1-Eulerangles.pdf) give us clear matrix for conversion of a vector from car reference $Fr^C$ to earth reference $Fr^E$. If $\vec V$ is a vector in different frames it is represented differently:

$$\vec V^E=L_{CE} \vec V^C$$

$$
L_{CE}^T=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos\theta \cos\psi & \sin\phi \sin\theta \cos\psi-\cos\phi \sin\psi & \cos\phi \sin\theta \cos\psi+\sin\phi \sin\psi \\
 \cos\theta \sin\psi & \sin\phi \sin\theta \sin\psi+\cos\phi \cos\psi & \cos\phi \sin\theta \sin\psi-\sin\phi \cos\psi \\
 -\cos\theta & \sin\phi \cos\theta & \cos\phi \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Here $L_{CE}$ is a conversion matrix made of so many angles' sin and cosin. Here, I prefer to avoid those angles. Instead if axis $x$ in earth frame is $\vec e^E_x$ and in car frame $\vec e^C_x$ then is there any conversion using $\vec e^E_x$ and $\vec e^C_x$ instead of angles. Alternatively, I can ask how can I represent $L_{CE}$ using $\vec e^E_x$ and $\vec e^C_x$ instead of angles?

Comment: Just having one vector in both reference frames is not sufficient. For example, knowing where the nose of a plane is pointing does not fix its orientation: it might be performing a roll.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks. I am fine even with using $\vec e_y$ or $\vec e_z$ but not angles.